# Django update table data using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, forms

I'm trying to filter table data and then update the table using ajax. I have:

**filter form:**

```
<form id="search" method="POST" action="{% url 'article-filter' %}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield1" name="txtSearch">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default js-filter">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def article_filter(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        search = request.POST.get('txtSearch')
        articles = Article.objects.filter(title = search)
        context = {
                   'articles': articles
        }
        data['html_table'] = render_to_string('blog/article_table.html',
                             context,
                             request = request
                             )
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**ajax handler:**

```
<script>
    var filter =
    function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "blog/article-filter", 
            dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#article-table').html(response.html_table);
        }
        });
    };

    $("#search").on("submit", ".js-filter", filter);
</script>
```

But when I submit the form, it only prints out raw html text (the table), how do I actually replace the table within the page and render it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the ajax didn't even happen. I edited the ajax to form submit and not the submit button:

```
$("#search").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "blog/article-filter",
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#article-table').html(data.html_table);
    });
});
```

And it is working just about fine.